# How to set tomcat session timeout per path?

Tags: java, tomcat8

I know how to change the global `session-timeout` in a `tomcat8`:

```
<session-config>
  <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

Question: how can I change the timeout **per application path**?

Like I want to deploy multiple applications to:

```
/myapp/v1
/myapp/v2
/myapp/v3
/someapp
```

Now I want all `/myapp/*` path to have a different timeout. But also only on the testserver. On the production server the timeout should be kept to default tomcat 30mins.

That's why I don't want to add a `web.xml` to the app itself, as this would also affect the production deployment when a new `war` is deployed.

Is that possible at all?

If that matters: I'm using `spring-boot`.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to probably handle this within a sessionhandler class, something along the lines of this:

```
public class AppHttpSessionListener implements HttpSessionListener {

    @Override
    public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent event) {
        event.getSession().setMaxInactiveInterval(15 * 60); 
    }

    @Override
    public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent event) {
        // session destroyed
    }
}
```

Ref: http://www.groupkt.com/post/7ee95bbd/session-timeout-handling-in-java.htm

I could be wrong, but I'm not sure you can do this!